# How to write the code for upload the image and save the image in database and the selected folder in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

Please anyone explain briefly where the code is placed. and give one sample code to save the image in database and the selected folder

I use this code in the models

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    if (isset($this->varImage))
    {
        $this->varImage=UploadedFile::getInstance($this,'varImage');
        if (is_object($this->varImage))
        {
            $path = Yii::$app->basePath . '/uploads/';  //set directory path to save image
            $this->varImage->saveAs($path.$this->intUsertypeId."_".$this->varImage);   //saving img in folder
            $this->varImage = $this->intUsertypeId."_".$this->varImage;                     //appending id to image name            
            //\Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
            //->update('organization', ['logo' => $this->logo], 'id = "'.$this-   >id.'"')
            //->execute(); //manually update image name to db
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me try to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? If yes, please show the code

Comment: Can you please also mention the error you are getting?

Comment: After uploading the file the following error will be displayed.

Error (#1).

An internal server error occurred.

The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.

Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.

Comment: basically you should add file path with name to Database and save within folder. complete guide provided here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html

Answer (score 0):

To save an uploaded image in a selected folder: (keep in mind that $image in both examples is an UploadForm instance https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/input-file-upload.md)

```
    $image->file = UploadedFile::getInstance( $image, 'file' );

    if ($image->file && $image->validate())
    {
    $tmp = '/anyfolder/' . array_pop( explode( '/', $image->file->tempName ) );
    $user->image = $tmp;
    $user->save();
    $image->file->saveAs( Yii::getAlias( '@webroot' ) . $tmp . '.' . $image->file->extension );

    }
```

tempName helps you to save the image with a unique name given by the system. The code above also saves the relational path of the $image in image( a string to keep the address) field of $user.

Now to save an uploaded image as a blob in database:

```
    $image->file = UploadedFile::getInstance( $image, 'file' );

    if ($image->file)
    {
    $user->image_blob = file_get_contents( $image->file->tempName );
    $user->save();

    }
```

Comment: At least UploadedFile::getInstance() has to execute in the context of a POST request. You can transfer some of the logic of "if blocks" to your model.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is your controller code:

$fileupload = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
          if(!empty($fileupload)){
              $fileupload->saveAs('uploads/' . $fileupload->baseName . '.' . $fileupload->extension);
              $model->file = $fileupload->baseName . '.' . $fileupload->extension;
              $model->save();
          }
For this code to work: your database field name should be file. And the image saved will go to the the folder uploads located inside the web directory.

In model:
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //other rules
            [['file'], 'safe']
        ];
    }

Note: Do not make the file required in rules.

In your view:

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput() ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: In this code image can' t move uploads folder  my uploads folder placed   frontend/web/uploads

Comment: have you tried to use this code in your controller?

Comment: Sorry! Image not move to folder.I don't know what is problem

Answer (score 0):

USe this code: This code is uploading your image to the folder uploads but not in database. Use this code to edit yours.

This is controller code.

```
public function actionCreate()
  {
      $model = new Your_model();

      if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

          $fileupload = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
          if(!empty($fileupload)){
              $fileupload->saveAs('uploads/' . $fileupload->baseName . '.' . $fileupload->extension);
          }

          return $this->redirect(['index']);
      } else {
          return $this->render('create', [
              'model' => $model,
          ]);
      }
  }
```

In model you just have to give a rule for image.

```
[['file'], 'safe']
```

Note: do not declare 'file' in required rule.

In your view:

```
<div class="product-form">

        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

         <?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput() ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>

        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

    </div>
```

i have edited my code a little bit. Try this one and let me know if there is some error. Do not forget to provide Read and Write permission to the uploads folder.

Hoping this will work.